# Return multiple match index lookups into one cell with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a case where I need to return all results in a column where 2 criteria are met into one cell.
My table looks something like this

```
+-----------+------+-------+
|    Job    | Type | Name  |
+-----------+------+-------+
| Tree      | AA   | Bob   |
| Apple     | FF   | John  |
| Banana    | FF   | John  |
| Grape     | CC   | James |
| Mango     | FF   | Paul  |
| Chocolate | AA   | Angus |
+-----------+------+-------+
```

​
And I currently use a formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Job],MATCH(1,(Table1[Name]=B12) * (Table1[Type]="FF"),0)),"")
```

Where B12 is an lookup name. However if I was to write John, I'd only get Apple. What I want is "Apple, Banana".
How would I go around doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF((Table1[Name]=B12) * (Table1[Type]="FF"),Table1[Job],""))
```

Being an array formula it must  be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

TEXTJOIN was introduced with Office 365 Excel.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Ive stumbled across a similar but different formula using REPT, which one would be better to use for peformance? `=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,REPT(Table1[Job],1*((Table1[Name]=B12)* (Table1[Type]="AA"))))`

Comment: @DanielJ never used REPT for something like this, so feel free to test.  I doubt you will find much difference between the two.